# Elasticsearh Sort With _score Fulltext

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am trying to sort using a script sort.
My script would look like: **_score * doc['someField'].value**
When I submit the query I am getting: unresolvable property or identifier:
_score

Is it not possible to use the score in a script sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the sort painless script, I guess not. But you could try to take a look at [function score query with a script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions). The original score can be used in the script as `_score`

Example:

```
        "script_score": {
            "script": {
                "source": "_score * doc['someField'].value"
            }
        }
```

Comment: You just need add `"track_scores": true` so you can use **_socre** in sort script